# What should I do with the Dragonstone?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In my inventory, I have a miscellaneous quest item that looks like a stone baseball base plate and has a weight of 25, the heaviest thing in my inventory. It's "Dragonstone". It has intricate designs on the front with some sort of creature's face at the bottom, and mystical inscription on the back. I don't remember what to do with it.

Comment: there's good seeding and bad seeding, and this is an example of bad seeding...

Comment: Does it matter that I posted it because I actually had this question?

Comment: yet you already had the answer when you posted.  I just feel this is a trivial question as the quest is in your journal and this is one of the first quests in the game.  Note, I didn't VTC since its technically a valid question, but I did downvote.

Comment: (1) I GOT AN answer because I looked it up in UESP. 
(2) I just went back to an old save to make sure: It seems that I retrieved the Dragonstone before/without even picking up the objective for it, so I honestly had no clue what to do with it. If you still don't believe me, I can post a video of my check. So, my saying "I don't remember what to do with it" isn't even apt; I should just say "What should I do with it?", or add a qualifier like ", if I was ever even told what to do with it if I got it". (3) The QUESTS log doesn't have a search function like Arqade does.

Comment: If you know a mod that adds a search function to the QUESTS log, that'd be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you take it from the boss enemy, you must return it to Farengar Secret-fire. He lives in Dragonsreach in Whiterun. He is the court wizard of Jarl Balgruuf the Greater.

Source: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bleak_Falls_Barrow_%28quest%29